# Mongoose find n records after specific record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a record with `ObjectId` that I know. I need to retrieve `n` number of records after the specific record.

So far, I've tried taking the timestamp of the "specific" record and then searched for records with timestamp greater than it, along with limiting the number of records.

But, what if the timestamps are same?

Can this be done? If yes, mongoose solution would be appreciated even more!

Answer (score 2):

Simply `sort` the cursor by `_id` and `limit` the result to `n`

```
db.collection.find({'_id': {'$gt': record_id } }).sort({'_id': 1}).limit(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId contains a timestamp with millisecond precision, so chance of having same timestamp for two objects is near zero!

In order to sort by ObjectId you can use this [post](http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/converting-objectid-to-dates-in-aggregation).